# Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts VB.NET LINUX

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, server, cpanel

I'm trying to connect a MySQL database (Linux server) with vb.net. I'm developing an app with a login and registration page.

```
'test connection

con.ConnectionString = "Server=41.76.109.93 ; Uid=Marissa; Pwd=mypassword; Database=MarissaDB;"

        Try
            con.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connected")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Error: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

I added a wildcard (%), checked the user privileges, downloaded the connector. Nothing works.

I also tried adding the port in two different ways.

1

```
'test connection

con.ConnectionString = "Server=41.76.109.93; Port=3306; Uid=Marissa; Pwd=mypassword; Database=MarissaDB;"

        Try
            con.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connected")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

2

```
'test connection

con.ConnectionString = "Server=41.76.109.93:3306; Uid=Marissa; Pwd=mypassword; Database=MarissaDB;"

        Try
            con.Open()
            MessageBox.Show("Connected")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that the MySQL server is listening for external connections?

Comment: @matigo Yes, I have.

Comment: Please try "User ID=Marissa" instead of "Uid=Marissa".
Have you tried to connect on Linux machine from MySQL Client?
Have you tried Telnet?

Comment: @Vlada I tried User ID=Marissa, but it still doesn't work. No, I have not. I've never used Telnet.

Comment: https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/ Server=myServerAddress;Port=1234;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;  What provider are you using, what Imports?

Comment: @Mary User Accounts on Cpanel (https://cpanel.net/) MySql database